# Windows OS does not recognise USB disk formatted by Samsung smart TV

Tags: usb, tv, window

I have an USB storage device that is formatted by my Samsung Smart TV.
I've recorded some TV shows on it.

I want to transfer these video files to my PC that has Windows.

The PC doesn't open the USB storage and raises the massage "You need to format the disk before you can use it".

What can I do to access (transfer) the files via USB?

Comment: Please post a screenshot from *Disk Management*. To open it press Win+R and type `diskmgmt.msc`, then press Enter.

Comment: What file system does this disk use.  You might have to use a Linux tool to determine this.

Comment: the file system is fat32.

Answer (score 0):

USB drive in Samsung Smart TV gets formatted in Linux-format filesystem (somebody says "XFS", mine is in "Linux Ext").

You can use free DiskInternals Linux Reader to view all files, but I think they are encrypted and/ord DRM protected, so youcan copy them to PC, but can't play them.